# SFINAE constexpr error in Microsoft Visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++17, constexpr, sfinae

Simple SFINAE code using `constexpr` fails to compile. The same code compiles in **g++**.

This issue comes only when `constexpr` is used. While using `std::is_integral_v<T>`, it compiles.

```cpp
// test code
#include<iostream>

template<typename T>
constexpr inline bool is_integral() {
    return std::is_integral_v<T>;
}

template<typename T>
constexpr inline bool is_floating_point() {
    return std::is_floating_point_v<T>;
}

struct tester {
template<typename T>
std::enable_if_t<is_integral<T>(), void> operator()(int* p){
    //integral version
    std::cout<<"integral\n";
}
template<typename T>
std::enable_if_t<is_floating_point<T>(), void> operator()(int* p){
    //floating point version
    std::cout<<"floating\n";
}


  template <typename T, typename... Args>
  std::enable_if_t<!is_integral<T>() && !is_floating_point<T>(), void> operator()(Args&&...)
  {
    std::cerr<<"not supported.\n";
  }
};


enum class type { INT, FLOAT, STRING};

void type_dispatcher(type tp) {
    tester t;
    switch(tp) {
        case type::INT:
            t.operator()<int>(nullptr);
            break;
        case type::FLOAT:
            t.operator()<float>(nullptr);
            break;
        default:
            std::cout<<"Unsupported\n";
    }
}

int main() {
    type t1{type::INT}, t2{type::FLOAT}, t3{type::STRING};
    type_dispatcher(t1);
    type_dispatcher(t2);
    type_dispatcher(t3);
    return 0;
}
```

**Error:** `cl.exe /std:c++17 ..\sfinae_test.cpp`

```cpp
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.29.30136 for x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

sfinae_test.cpp
..\sfinae_test.cpp(21): error C2535: 'enable_if<0,void>::type tester::operator ()(int *)': member function already defined or declared
..\sfinae_test.cpp(16): note: see declaration of 'tester::operator ()'
..\sfinae_test.cpp(44): error C2672: 'tester::operator ()': no matching overloaded function found
..\sfinae_test.cpp(44): error C2893: Failed to specialize function template 'enable_if<0,void>::type tester::operator ()(int *)'
..\sfinae_test.cpp(16): note: see declaration of 'tester::operator ()'
..\sfinae_test.cpp(44): note: With the following template arguments:
..\sfinae_test.cpp(44): note: 'T=float'
```

Folding all the code into `if constexpr` works.
Related issue: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/constexpr-function-in-sfinae/1048586

Is there any solution/hack to this problem?

Comment: Compiled successfully https://godbolt.org/z/5547Ga7Ed. The first two templates are not used.

Comment: @S.M.: OP showed working example ( :-( ) and explain the wrong one (using the unused methods) [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/3Wsa6EK5d).

Comment: My bad. Updated the code. When first 2 templates are used, it fails to compile.

Comment: *"Is there any solution/hack to this problem?"* You already found bug report and work-arounds (using directly `std::is_integral_v<T>` or `if constexpr`), not sure what else you want.

Comment: I am using `constexpr` function because the conditions inside are complex. So, I am looking for solution/hack to use `constexpr` or somehow allow usage of complex conditions without being too verbose.

Comment: You might store the result in `constexpr` (template)variable [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/bzvW3oMGs)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `enable_if` as template parameter, like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/n6oo9bxfe).